# I have been trying to install a jdk7u10 and im having trouble installing it after its downloaded

Tags: java

I get an error called "C:.......\jdk-7u10-windows-i586.exe is not a valid Win32 application" what is wrong?

Comment: Have you installed the right version (32 vs 64 bits) for the right OS ( Windows)?

Comment: It means it didn't download properly. I would try the 64-bit version if you can. If you have a 32-bit OS, you can only run 32-bit applications.

Comment: @assylias IMO 32 bit and 64 bit issue wont give a "not a valid Win32 application" error.

Comment: I have windows 7! and I did download the 32bit version which my pc supports. Does downloading the jre 1st cause a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

The file is probably corrupt. Download it again.